# первый раз вижу такое в PHP - что это такое?

Tags: php

Увидел тут недавно такое:

```
<?php } ?>
...
<?php } else { ?>
```

Первый раз такое встретил, что это и как понять это?
Код похож на какой-то закрывающий тег. Это увидел я в CMS "Joomla" (хотя и в движок CMS "Joomla" залез впервые (не перевариваю её - но кризис заставил). В других CMS такого не наблюдал.)
Зачем так делать? И рационально ли это?

Comment: и что тут необычного? обычна конструкция `if/else` со скобками. раньше все так и делали, пока не начали пользоваться альтернативным синтаксисом

Comment: Я не вижу что тут не обычное такое? Все что вы пишите в документе, интерпретатору не интересно, а вот то что написано в <?php он и должен обрабатывать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

То, что находиться за пределами `<?php` и `?>` не будет обработано интерпретатором. У Вас там судя по всему фрагменты `html` разметки. Это называется [Изолированием от html](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)

Например:

```
<ul>
    <?php 
$act = false;
if ($act == true) { ?>
    <li>
        Элемент списка
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
    <li>
        Второй пункт меню
    </li>
</ul>
```

В данном примере "Элемент списка" не будет выведен, так как условие не выполняется.

Comment: Ясно, а я обычно использую такую разметку:
`<ul>
    <?php 
    $act = false;
    if ($act == true) { 
    print "<li>
        Элемент списка
    </li>";
}
?>
    <li>
        Второй пункт меню
    </li>
</ul>`
Я думаю, это же полностью идентично с точки зрения скорости обработки кода?

Comment: И тот и тот вариант лучше не рассматривать (забыть), так как поддерживать такой код будет мягко говоря весьма проблематично. Вам следует почитать на тему _шаблонизаторов_.